# How to extract information with Xpath in python scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i need some help to extract a part of information from html page with xpath! i wanna extract the review's rating 
exemple : this is the `HTML` code

```
<div id="BVRRRatingOverall_Rating_Summary_1" class="BVRRRating BVRRRatingNormal BVRRRatingOverall">
<div class="BVRRLabel BVRRRatingNormalLabel">Overall rating&nbsp;</div>
<div class="BVRRRatingNormalImage"><img src="/4_9/5/rating.gif" class="BVImgOrSprite" alt="4.9 out of 5" title="4.9 out of 5" width="85" height="16"></div>
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" class="BVRRRatingNormalOutOf">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue" class="BVRRNumber BVRRRatingNumber">4.9</span>
      <span class="BVRRSeparatorText">out of </span>
      <span itemprop="bestRating" class="BVRRNumber BVRRRatingRangeNumber">5</span>
      <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="23">
   </span>
</div>
```

From this code i wanna display "4.9 out of 5" or 3 variables which contains "4.9" , "out of" , "5"

I used this but it didn't work :

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="BVRRRatingNormalImage"]/img/@alt').extract()
```

Any help?

Comment: For this html example should work this xpath expression:
`//img[@class="BVImgOrSprite"]/@alt`. 
But without site link and some example of your code, I don't  know if it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="aggregateRating"]/span/text()').extract()
```

it will give three element in list format

```
response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/text()').extract_first()
```

it will give only one element as string "4.9"